# Checking for multiple items in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, pygame

I have a list of strings and am trying to check if all the elements in this list are in another list. I know there is a way to do this by individually asking if each element in the list is in the second list, but it seems like there should be a better way that would stream-line the code. I am working with Python 3 and pygame.

code:

```
 self.loot=[] #keep track of what each player has gotten
 self.pieces=["necklace", "ring", "bracelet", "earring", "crown"]#possible jewelry
```

then throughout the game pieces are added into loot list. I could do this by...

```
  if "crown" in self.loot :
        if "bracelet" in self.loot :
            if "necklace" in self.loot :
                if "earring" in self.loot :
                    if "ring" in self.loot :
                        if "black ring" not in self.loot :
                            end_message = gmaes.Message(value = self.name "is the Prettiest Princess",
                                                        size= 75,
                                                        color = color.pink,
                                                        x = games.screen.width/2,
                                                        y = games.screen.height/2,
                                                        lifetime = 5* games.screen.fps,
                                                        after_death = games.screen.quit)
                            games.screen.add(end_message)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use a more appropriate data structure, i.e. `set`

```
required = set(['ring','erring','etc'])
have = set(loot)
if not (required - have):
   ....
```

The idea is that the `-` will remove all the things from `required` which are in `have`. If the result is empty, you have everything.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
if all(req in loot for req in required):
    ....
```

This will iterate through the `required` and check if each `req` is in `loot`. If every result is `True` it will return `True`.